# DrawerLayout showing a little bit while pressing (holding) on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using `DrawerLayout` to have a `RecyclerView` as menu because I need to control and update the menu programmatically.

I want the menu to be opened/closed only by swipe and a button click but the problem is, when I press and hold on anything from my main layout, the drawer shows up a little bit and my click to the button will fail. The click works however when you quickly press it.

Btw I am not an Android user. Is this a system or Android default behavior or anything?

Here is the demo if I'm not clear

[image]

And here is the pseudo code for my layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        ... />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        .../>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: is it happening only when you click on the button or anywhere on the screen? It's a common problem and I might have a work-around

Comment: @Rainmaker It happens to anywhere on the screen. I am currently looking at ways to override the gesture detector and disable the long press. Not sure if that will help or not but any help is appreciated!

Comment: yeah, my idea was to override the long click and put there mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED); and then mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED); when you want to enable it again

Comment: @Rainmaker Thanks! Do you have a sample code to put in as an answer so that I don't need to search around lol? I am really an iOS guy and very new to Android

Comment: yeah, just a min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally did it by creating subclass for `DrawerLayout` and override the onInterceptTouchEvent method. The idea is that when press down, force the menu to be closed. Otherwise unlock it.

Here is the subclass which is now replacing the original drawerlayout in my xml file.

```
public class CustomDrawer extends DrawerLayout {
    public CustomDrawer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        } else {
            setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

And layout pseudo code

```
<...CustomDrawer
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...
    ...
</...CustomDrawer>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your layout xml to your layout tag add properties clickable and focusable

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.project.wordsdict.main.views.AboutActivity"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true">
```

Then in your activity in onCreate method find your layout by id

```
    ConstraintLayout mLayout = findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutId);
    mLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                 mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKE‌​D_CLOSED);
                    return true;
                }
            });

mLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                return false;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOC‌​KED);
                return true; 
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

P.S use whatever layout you're using. Hope it works as it's definitively a bug of DrawerLayout

Comment: Thank you for the code but it's not working for me. The longClickListener is not even reached. I did it by creating subclass for DrawerLayout and override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method

Answer (score 0):

You can have an activity containing the menu and then make the rest of the activities that need to use the menu implement that activity.

For example.

BaseActivity - containing the menu:

```
import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public static DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
           .......
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks
        Intent intent;
        int id = item.getItemId();
        ActivityOptions options =
                ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
        switch (id) {
           ..............

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Activity with the Recycler view:

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null, false);
    BaseActivity.drawer.addView(contentView, 0);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    // Lookup the recycler view in activity layout
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    // Initialize arrayList
    ArrayList<....> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();

    // Create adapter
    YourAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(...);

    // Attach the adapter to the recycler view
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Populate the recycler view
    adapter.addData();

    // Set layout manager to position the items
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2,
            GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

}
```

your_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_column="2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: So your suggestion is to use some other layout other than the Drawer Layout?

Comment: Yeah, use a different Layout and have a BaseActivity which layout resource file is Drawer Layout and make the other activities extend BaseActivity